# Parsing comma-separated digits in ksh

Tags: shell, ksh, string

I have a variable in ksh that can contain no more then 2 comma-separated digits (white spaces allowed). Something like:

```
a="1,2"
a="1 ,2" 
a="1,"
a="0,0"
```

I want a loop to

- read through `$a`
- exit if there is more than one `,`
- assign `m=a[1]` and `n=a[2]`

Comment: What does `more then one` mean?

Comment: if a="1,2,3" or "1,2, " then exit. no more than one comma

Answer (score 4):

```
for a in "1,2" "1 ,2" "1," "0,0" "0,0,0" "2,3"; do
    case "$a" in
        *,*,*) printf 'Too many commas: "%s"\n' "$a" >&2
               exit 1
    esac
    IFS=', ' read m n <<<"$a"
    printf 'm = %d, n = %d\n' "$m" "$n"
done
```

This produces

```
m = 1, n = 2
m = 1, n = 2
m = 1, n = 0
m = 0, n = 0
Too many commas: "0,0,0"
```

when running under `ksh93` (or `bash` or `zsh`).

Setting `IFS` to a space and a comma before `read` makes `read` split the contents of `$a` on these two characters (or multiples of them).  The remaining data is assigned to `m` and `n`.

If a string is something like `"2,3 4"`, then `n` would be assigned the value `3 4`.

Note also that on the third line of output (parsing `"1,"`), `m` is shown as zero only because we're using the `%d` format specifier with `printf`. If interpreted as a string, the variable `m` is empty.